# Bugs in reading and writing to text file

Tags: java, android, text-files, textfield, read-write

I am developing an app, in which the user puts some numeric info in some text fields, the app is supposed to write the info into a txt file for later use, for example next time the app is opened or a refresh button is pressed the numbers should be read from the file and loaded into the same text fields so the user can change them if needed. While both "writer" and "loader" functions seem to be working, the problem is that every time "loader" is being called, it loads the data from some previously saved file and not the file that is created right now by the "writer". If the user wants the new saved data to be loaded into text fields, he needs to close and reopen the app again. To explain the situation better, I placed some scenario after the codes. Any ideas what is wrong and what can be done?

Here is the code that I'm using to put the info into the file, and it works fine:

```
    public void writer(View view){                               
    try {

        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("myfilename", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE | Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        PrintStream prntst = new PrintStream(fos);
        txtEditor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        prntst.println (txtEditor.getText().toString());
        txtEditor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText02);
        prntst.println (txtEditor.getText().toString());   
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

And here is the code I'm using to read the info from file to some ArrayList, then this ArrayList is used to fill up the textfields, this is also working fine (fine means without error):

```
    public void reader(View view){
    try {

        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("myfilename")));            
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputReader);     
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {             
              String line = scanner.nextLine();
              bld.add(line);
            }

        inputReader.close();
        scanner.close();
        txtEditor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        txtEditor.setText(bld.get(0));          
        txtEditor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText02);
        txtEditor.setText(bld.get(1));


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();            
        txtEditor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        bld.add((txtEditor.getText().toString()));
        txtEditor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText02);
        bld.add((txtEditor.getText().toString()));           
    }
}
```

Scenario:

1. User opens the app, there are some default values in text fields (two textfields), the user changes the values to 2 and 3 respectively, and touches the save button.
2. User changes the values again but instead of touching the save button he hits the load button, now the app is supposed to load 2 and 3 into fields (which are saved) but instead, it loads the defaults values.
3. User closes the app and reopens them, this time 2 and 3 are shown as default in textfields. Seems like the "loader" NOW is reading the data from the previously saved file.
4. User changes the values from "2 and 3" to "13 and 14" and hits save and load button respectively, but 2 and 3 are loaded into fields.
5. User closes and reopens the app again, this time 13 and 14 are shown.

PS. the variable bld is global and defined in the MainActivity:

```
    ArrayList<String> bld = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Thank you,

Comment: To enhance readability, please add an empty line after `Scenario:` to display the text as an ordered list.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, actually I'm a newbie in this forum. I keep your advice for the next time I post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be with the global ArrayList variable 'bld'. It's OK to define it globally, But initialize it locally.

The problem is that, you are calling as `bld.get(0)`, But the new values are appended after it.

Add the line `bld = new ArrayList<String>();`
inside your 'reader' function.

Answer (score 1):

In the writer method you're closing the file output stream:

```
fos.close();
```

But surely you should be closing the print stream instead.

```
prntst.close();
```

Closing the print stream will flush the stream and then close the underlying output stream. When you close the output stream, it won't know anything about the print stream constructed on top of it, so won't know to flush it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and tip. I tried it but the problem still exists. I also tried flushing by prntst.flush(); :(

Comment: Have a look at Nizam's answer - I think he might have spotted the real problem.